# How to remove unnecessary classes from app.(hash).css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webpack, vue.js

I'm using `webpack` to build my project (generated by `vue-cli`). 
I use `bootstrap`(only the `css` part, the `js` part is unnecessary for me) as the `UI framework`.

I'm using only a small percentage of classes defined by `bootstrap`, for example only `alert` and `alert-warning` (a bit exaggerated, in reality, I used about 3% bootstrap classes).

I want to know whether there is a loader or plugin  to remove unnecessary classes when generating `app.css`?

Comment: You can comment them in `scss` or `less` version.

Comment: @Damon.s i'm quite a newbie for scss or less. Can you give a more detailed solution.(i've tried import scss but had trouble dealing with scss variables.)